# PHPIDS configuration to allow html

Tags: php, tinymce, htmlpurifier

I have scoured the https://phpids.org website, multiple forums, stackoverlow (of course :P) etc to find a way to allow posting html string from TinyMCE textarea integrated in my homegrown CMS. I tried to include it in html[] array in the phpids **Config.ini** like this:

```
; define which fields contain html and need preparation before 
; hitting the PHPIDS rules (new in PHPIDS 0.5)
; html[]          = POST.__wysiwyg
html[]          = POST.content_text
```

However, it didn't work! It still detect the posted string as malicious! It would work if I include exceptions like this:

```
; define which fields shouldn't be monitored...
exceptions[]    = GET.__utmz
exceptions[]    = GET.__utmc
exceptions[]    = POST.content_text
exceptions[]    = REQUEST.content_text
```

But I do not want it as an exception. Has anyone encountered the same problem?
BTW, I'm using the latest 0.7 version for PHPIDS.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you found a solution yet? i'm stuck at the same situation.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to put your input into https://demo.phpids.org/ and post the results in your question. Please state the input you provided, its output and the output you expect.

Perhaps you have to programmatically enable "Harmless HTML is allowed" in your code.

Hope that helps...